# I am getting the runtime error of message = "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION"; while using the below code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am running a chat app code , it is giving me the authentication runtime error. Error message is shown below.
I tried several things but nothing worked out yet, if you need another code related information do let me know.

thanks in advance

the code is AppDelegate.Swift file

```
internal func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (authUser, error) in
            guard Auth.auth().currentUser != nil else {
                print(error!)
                abort()
            }
            self.uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, forKey: "uid")
            let user = User(id: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, name: "ぼく")
            UserRepository.shared.save(user)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Error Message

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000016744b0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION";
            reason = invalid;
        }
    );
    message = "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION";
}}}}
```

Comment: Check your settings in your Firebase dashboard and enable signing in anonymously.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the Anonymous login in your Firebase Console. Take a look at the picture and enable the marked switch. You can find the Firebase Console [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/).

[image]

Comment: yes it did worked, but there are some more issues but it's not related to this.

Comment: I enabled it but still getting the same issue.

Comment: The iOS comment docs say "`FIRAuthErrorCodeOperationNotAllowed` - Indicates that anonymous accounts are not enabled. Enable them in the Auth section of the Firebase console." Which is a different code. I guess it's just wrong.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [Constantin Beer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9696675/constantin-beer)  answer (i'e enabling the anonymous sign in method from firebase), google has enrolled this new beta feature (the identity platform) where you would need to check Enable create (sign up) option. This is mentioned nowhere in the documentation yet, [Alex Kozlowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7038954/alex-kozlowski) spent a lot of time figuring this out. Please refer the image below

[image]

Comment: I want to thank you very much, as long as Alex Kozlowski, because I was completely lost on this issue and you've made my day.

Comment: Where can I find these Identity Platform settings?

Comment: @Joel Brostrom, go to your google cloud console -> search for "Identity platform" in the top middle search section (The one with placeholder "Search products and resources") -> It will ask you to enable the API -> once you do it you will be taken to a page mentioned in the answer -> from there navigate to settings section, you will see the options there.

Comment: Had to say thank you too - this is the piece I was missing, which as the answer states, does not appear to be documented anywhere (that I could find at least).